# Table fields cannot be bound

Tags: sql-server

This works in MS SQL :

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT SUM(P.bedrag) AS ex
FROM         dbo.verkopen AS P INNER JOIN
                      (SELECT DISTINCT dbo.verkopen.ino
                        FROM          dbo.verkopen INNER JOIN
                                               dbo.doss ON dbo.verkopen.ino =         dbo.doss.ino         INNER     JOIN
                                               dbo.vdagbk ON dbo.verkopen.ino = dbo.vdagbk.ino
                        WHERE      (dbo.doss.uitvoerder LIKE 'LL') AND (dbo.doss.dosno LIKE '101520')) AS C ON C.ino = P.ino
```

I had to do it like that as there were some rows duplicated in my result.

**But I want to do something like this with it :**

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT doss.dosno, doss.dosnm, SUM(P.bedrag) AS TotBedraggefactureerd, SUM(P.betaald) AS TotBetaald, SUM(P.totincl) AS TotIncl, 
                  SUM(vdagbk.beginsaldo) AS totbeginsaldoontvangen, SUM(vdagbk.eindsaldo) AS toteindsaldoontvangen, 
                  SUM(CASE vdagbk.reden WHEN 'H' THEN vdagbk.bedrag END) AS ontvangenhonoraria, SUM(CASE vdagbk.reden WHEN 'P' THEN vdagbk.bedrag END) 
                  AS ontvangenprov, SUM(CASE vdagbk.reden WHEN 'A' THEN vdagbk.bedrag END) AS dagboekA, SUM(CASE vdagbk.reden WHEN 'G' THEN vdagbk.bedrag END) 
                  AS dagboekG, SUM(CASE vdagbk.reden WHEN 'E' THEN vdagbk.bedrag END) AS dagboekE
FROM         dbo.verkopen AS P INNER JOIN
                      (SELECT DISTINCT dbo.verkopen.ino
                        FROM          dbo.verkopen INNER JOIN
                                               dbo.doss ON dbo.verkopen.ino = dbo.doss.ino INNER JOIN
                                               dbo.vdagbk ON dbo.verkopen.ino = dbo.vdagbk.ino
                        WHERE      (dbo.doss.uitvoerder LIKE 'LL') AND (dbo.doss.dosno LIKE '101520')) AS C ON C.ino = P.ino
 GROUP BY doss.dosno, doss.dosnm
 ORDER BY doss.dosno
```

I know it is all messed up now. I can do a little SQL but this is a bit over my head to rearrange.

I know it only contains .ino but what do I put where now in the query.

I had this :

```
`SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT doss.dosno, doss.dosnm, SUM(verkopen.bedrag)/2 AS TotBedraggefactureerd, SUM(verkopen.betaald) AS TotBetaald, SUM(verkopen.totincl) 
                     AS TotIncl, SUM(vdagbk.beginsaldo) AS totbeginsaldoontvangen, SUM(vdagbk.eindsaldo) AS toteindsaldoontvangen, 
                     SUM(CASE vdagbk.reden WHEN 'H' THEN vdagbk.bedrag END) AS ontvangenhonoraria, SUM(CASE vdagbk.reden WHEN 'P' THEN vdagbk.bedrag END) 
                     AS ontvangenprov, SUM(CASE vdagbk.reden WHEN 'A' THEN vdagbk.bedrag END) AS dagboekA, SUM(CASE vdagbk.reden WHEN 'G' THEN vdagbk.bedrag END) 
                     AS dagboekG, SUM(CASE vdagbk.reden    WHEN 'E' THEN vdagbk.bedrag END) AS dagboekE
FROM            verkopen INNER JOIN
                     doss ON verkopen.ino = doss.ino INNER JOIN
                     vdagbk ON verkopen.ino = vdagbk.ino
 WHERE        (dbo.doss.uitvoerder LIKE 'LL') AND (dbo.doss.dosno LIKE '101520')    GROUP BY doss.dosno, doss.dosnm
ORDER BY doss.dosno
`
```

but that returned the result double in some cases.

Comment: Some points of interest that you might find useful: First, you can get rid of the "Top (100) Percent" bit. That just complicates your code and does nothing.  Second, SQL-Server isn't afraid of a few extra line breaks. So you can make your code easier to read by putting your totbeginsaldoontvangen and TotBedraggefactureerd and all the others on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

In your SELECT, only the aliases `P` and `C` are available.

The `doss` and `vdagbk` aliases are internal to the derived table: and the derived table only returns `dbo.verkopen.ino` anyway.

I'd consider removing the derived table and just joining directly

Answer (score 0):

Your `ino` is the primary key, yes? In that case, you should investigate the duplicates by finding some specific examples.  Look for those `ino` values in your 3 source tables. At least 1 of those tables probably has duplicate values.

Comment: Yes I know there are doubles when using mine (second query) ; using the first query it 'removed' those doubles somehow. So I would like to implement that query-method into third query. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: `Select Distinct` would probably do the trick, but I strongly recommend you first investigate why there are doubles in the first place.  You may find complications in the source data that need to be dealt with somehow.